# Using external @DatabaseView not working in Room

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I'm trying to create a @databaseView from an already created DatabaseView externally.

Let's call It `"ProductView"`

Since ProductView already exist in the database I try to import it in some way.

```
@SkipQueryVerification
@DatabaseView(
    value = "SELECT * FROM ProductView"
)

 error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: main.ProductView)
```

Or like this:

```
@DatabaseView(
    value = "SELECT * FROM " +
        "ProductView",
    viewName = "ProductView"
)


error: Circular reference detected among views: ProductView
```

But it doesn't work.

the `data class ProductView()` have all the correct variables.

Is this possible to access a database view created externally via room? Or do I need to use SQLLightOpenHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I solved this by using @RawQuery to access the view directly